# Upload multiple files in nodejs express with destination name as a new object id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I'm working on Nodejs, Express and Mongodb backend (and postman). I want to get form data fields from postman which are `title`, `subject`, `coverPhoto` and `attachment` where title and subject are text fields (in postman form-data) and coverPhoto and attachment are files.

**What I want:**
I have a schema for book like -

```
const bookSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  subject{
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  coverPhoto{
    type: String,
  },
  attachment{
    type: String
  }
});
```

and a router such as -

```
router.post('/book',[//express-validator checks] , (req,res) => 
{
    //... some code ...
    let book = new bookSchema({title,subject,coverPhoto,attachment}); // save to schema
});
```

I want to make a new mongo bookSchema object where I will save paths for coverPhoto and attachment in their respective fields.

Problem: I want each book to be saved in a separate directory based on their object id (which the new object will return i.e `book._id` (mongoose id))
e.g `/uploads/60d4cdc5c6f54c051cf01fed/cover-image.png` and `/uploads/60d4cdc5c6f54c051cf01fed/book.pdf`

I have tried as much as I could with multer but I can't achieve this desired output. If anyone can help please do.

Comment: All these `title,subject,coverPhoto,attachment` you are getting from request object, now multer will give you uploaded directory but unless you insert `coverPhoto` and `attachment` into mongodb collection you will not be getting `object_id`.

Comment: Umm I don't get how that answers my question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, that was my question, I missed to put `?` at the end

Comment: Yes until and unless I make a new mongoose object I won't get an id and I need that id for my directory name.

Comment: Actually Multer is used to save files in file disk system and not to your database directly. So you need save it using mongoose GridFS.

Comment: No I will save on disk system not GridFS, I just want that object id so I can use it to name my directory.

Comment: ok, then you can save it with `fs` module only, why you preferring `multer`?

Comment: Ok I'll try that